# Nginx shows 404 error for sub link and paths

Tags: nginx, laravel-5

I have using nginx for laravel project. When I use the domain name it shows the home page. But When I click any one of the link it does not work. And shows 404 Not Found error.

http://www.myhomepage.com          // working
http://www.myhomepage.com/about    // not working

I have using the following configuration.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        root /var/www/abc-company-website/public;

        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name myhomepage.com localhost;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to adjust the `location /` block to pass the query string, as per the documentation:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

[Laravel 5.8 Docs - Installation - Pretty URLs - Nginx](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/installation#pretty-urls)

Answer (score 0):

I also got a similar error when using `nodejs` + `nginx`, i relied on lagbox's answer and fixed it, i did the following:

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$query_string;
}
```